# In Javascript, is it possible to access a field's annotated data at run time?

Tags: javascript, annotations, babeljs

Given the example JavaScript code :

```
function foo = key => target => {
  target.key = key;

  return target;
}

class Bob {

  @foo('hello')
  a = 'world';

}

const bob = new Bob();
```

Is there a way to access the value of `key` from the annotated field at run-time? Something like :

```
getAnnotationTarget(bob, 'a').key;  // "hello"
```

The point of this question is to allow class field annotation, and retrieving data associated with that field from the annotation. The field's value itself should not be affected, i.e. `bob.a = "blah";` should not affect the annotation value associated with the field.

My naive thought was to extend the field's prototype from the annotation, but it seems unavailable when the annotation is executed.

Thank you.

Comment: [Here's the current state of the proposal I think](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators)

Comment: @Pointy yes, the feature is in stage 2, meaning that it is expected to be implemented in the language officially. And even though it is in draft, I do not expect much features to actually change, and will update the code accordingly. But the feature is still there for those who use a transpiler such as Babel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a (hidden) Map to the class, then look that up:

```
 const hidden = Symbol();

 decorator @foo(value) {
   @register((target, prop) => {
      if(!target[hidden]) target[hidden] = new Map();
      target[hidden].set(prop, value);
    }
 }

 const getAnnotationTarget = (instance, key) =>
    instance.constructor[hidden].get(key);
```

Or using the babel proposal syntax the decorator looks like:

```
 const foo = (value) => (target, prop) => {
    target = target.constructor;
    if(!target[hidden]) target[hidden] = new Map();
    target[hidden].set(prop, value);

 };
```

Comment: How would that work using `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators` ?